# Pandas dataframe- How to count the number of distinct rows for a given ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe and I want to add a column to it with the total of distinct `SalesOrderId` for a given `CustomerId`
[image]

So, with I am trying to do there would be a new column with the value 3 for all this rows.
How can I do it?

I am trying this way but I get an error

```
data['TotalOrders'] = data.groupby([['CustomerID','SalesOrderID']]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: The code you used collapsed the data frame, group it by a variable and count the number of occurrence of every group of 2 variables, so the result is a data frame with different shape than the original one. The result is a data frame so you cannot assign it to a column.

Answer (score 1):

Try using transform:

```
data['TotalOrders'] = df.groupby('CustomerID')['SalesOrderID'].transform('nunique')
```

This will give you one entry for each entry in the group.  (thanks @Rodalm)

Comment: You can simplify it to `df.groupby('CustomerID')['SalesOrderID'].transform('nunique')`

Comment: @Rodalm - yep - better.  I have to figure out how the quoted function name actually works.